# captureOffscreenArea in display.save() of ScrollViewWidget appears to have no effect

Tags: coronasdk

I have a ScrollViewWidget with a `scrollHeight` greater than the widget height.  I'd like to capture the entire contents of the widget using `display.save()` with `captureOffscreenArea = true`, but only the onscreen portion of the ScrollViewWidget is being saved.

This problem has [come up before](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/64933-captureoffscreenarea-does-not-capture-off-screen-areas/?p=335339), but I thought it had been fixed. I'm using the latest public build (2017.3068).  Any idea why this might not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Corona.  However, in the meantime, a workaround is to populate a GroupObject with another set of DisplayObjects identical to the ones being added to the ScrollViewWIdget (this may be costly/complicated) and using this GroupObject as the first argument to `display.save()` with `captureOffscreenArea = true`:

```
local _g = display.newGroup()

-- Populate _g with DisplayObjects identical to those in the
-- scroll view, but NOT the same objects (this would remove them
-- from the scroll view).

display.save( _g, {
    filename = "foo.jpg",
    baseDir = system.TemporaryDirectory,
    captureOffscreenArea = true
})
```